# How can I add custom buttons with custom event values in icCube 6 reporting?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

How can I add custom buttons with custom event values in icCube reporting v6 (similar to the Actions/Buttons widget in v5)? I didn't find this option in any of the filters & tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being I think **"Select Control" widget** is what you are looking for (*it is placed under "Filters & Tools" top menu)*.

- With its' "Data options" it is possible to define custom action (green border card). 
  [image]
- After this step you might want to configure custom action with it's advanced settings (1)

[image]

- Configuration of "Event type" field gives you a list of possibilities. Even to define onClick javascript callback (3)

[image]

Comment: Way of action item creation might change in further versions of icCube reporting.